# What's the song in the background of this video? The "noticable" part starts around 1:40 in

Tags: star-wars, music-identification

I believe Lucas King made the song, but not sure. Hope that helps.

Comment: You could ask the guy who created the video ?

Comment: Why would this forum have a music-identification tag if the subject was off-topic?  (*A tag devoted to the identification—and possible explanation—of musical cues or scores in a work.*)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the [***Droid Invasion Theme / Droid Invasion March***](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Droid_Invasion_Theme) written, arranged and conducted by John Williams and the London Symphony Orchestra, London Voices and The New London Children's Choir.

It appeared several times in the film [The Phantom Menace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_Episode_I_%E2%80%93_The_Phantom_Menace)

Comment: Thank you very much! :)

Comment: @TicktockTicktock - [What can I say?](https://i.giphy.com/media/aZ0QZElKZjVL2/giphy.webp)

Comment: Actually that's the wrong gif but I'm gonna pretend I meant to do that.

Comment: Hahah that's hilarious